# Passing a saved variable from jsonResponse payload is adding a minus-symbol to beginning of saved value

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon Studio to write a chain API test script. I'm sending a request and saving a value from the returned jsonResponse. For whatever reason, when I save the `transactionId` value from the jsonResponse anad pass it into the next API request URL, it's adding a `-` (minus symbol). I cannot figure out why it's doing it and I have checked every line of code to make sure I'm not unintentionally adding it anywhere.

Keyword File:

```
@Keyword
def int transferAcct(int customerId, int amount, int externalId, int accountId, String tag) {
    def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject("Postman/SampleWorkflow/transferNewAcct",
            ['customerId' : customerId, ('fromId') : externalId, 'toId' : accountId]))

    def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getResponseText())
    return jsonResponse.data[0].transactionId
    println("returned = " + jsonResponse.data[0].transactionId)
}

@Keyword
def getTransaction(int customerId, int transactionId) {
    def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject("Postman/SampleWorkflow/getTransaction",
            ['customerId' : customerId, 'transactionId' : transactionId]))

    def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getResponseText())
    return jsonResponse.data[0].typeCode
}
```

Sample Payload response from `transferAcct()`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "customerId": 100001,
      "tag": "",
      "transactionId": 2147529999
    }
  ],
  "errors": [],
  "status": 200
}
```

I save the `transactionId` as a variable and then pass it into the `getTransaction()` request URL.

But the request URL has a `-` added to the beginning of the `transactionId`.
Example: `https://fakeUrl.com/transaction/get/100001/-2147449999`

The only thing I can think of that might be causing the issue is that this is the only request in my test suite that immediately returns the values inside of an array `return jsonResponse.data[0].transactionId` --  all of my other requests return a dictionary of values (Example: `return jsonResponse.data.customerId`)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `transactionId` is actually a `long`, not an `int`. So it was changing the returned value. Updating the scripts to declare transactionId as a `long` fixed it.

```
@Keyword
def long transferAcct(int customerId, int amount, int externalId, int accountId, String tag) {
    def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject("Postman/SampleWorkflow/transferNewAcct",
            ['customerId' : customerId, ('fromId') : externalId, 'toId' : accountId]))

    def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getResponseText())
    return jsonResponse.data[0].transactionId
    println("returned = " + jsonResponse.data[0].transactionId)
}

@Keyword
def getTransaction(int customerId, long transactionId) {
    def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject("Postman/SampleWorkflow/getTransaction",
            ['customerId' : customerId, 'transactionId' : transactionId]))

    def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getResponseText())
    return jsonResponse.data[0].typeCode
}
```